# looping over an Object in a prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I know how to loop oven an Object I in javascript.
But when i try to do that inside a prototype of an Object then i am getting 'undefined is not a function' error. My code is as below

```js
var createObject = function(strIn) {
  this.result = strIn;
}

createObject.prototype.toObject = function() {
  var objData = this.result.split('&');
  this.result = Object.create(null); //{}
  var res = Object.create(null);
  objData.forEach(function(value, index) {
    var test = value.split('=')
    return res[test[0]] = test[1];
  });
  this.result = res;
  res = Object.create(null);
  return this.result;

}

createObject.prototype.toString = function() {
  //{ jake: 'dog', finn: 'human' }
  //"jake=dog&finn=human"
  var key,
    objIn = Object.create(null),
    returnresult = '';
  objIn = this.result; //this is causing issue
  console.log('obj', objIn);
  console.log(typeof(objIn))
  for (key in objIn) {
    console.log(objIn.hasOwnProperty('key')) //trying to see wht this results in ::GIVES 'undefined is not a function error'
      //     if(objIn.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      //       returnresult += key+'='+objIn[key]+'&'
      //     }
  }
  this.result = returnresult;
  returnresult = Object.create(null);
  return this.result;
}


var test = new createObject('jake=dog&finn=human');

console.log(test);
console.log(test.toObject())
console.log(test);
console.log(test.toString());
console.log(test);
```

Result and error as below is:

```
{ result: 'jake=dog&finn=human' } 
{ jake: 'dog', finn: 'human' } 
{ result: { jake: 'dog', finn: 'human' } } 
obj { jake: 'dog', finn: 'human' } 
object 
solution.js:52 
    console.log(objIn.hasOwnProperty('key')  ) 
                      ^ 
TypeError: undefined is not a function 
    at createObject.toString (solution.js:52:23) 
    at solution.js:68:18
```

Its not a spelling mistake so not sure whats going on ..

Thanks ..

Comment: Issue is in line 51 after createObject.prototype.toString = .... for (key in objIn){
    if(objIn.hasOwnProperty(key)){// this is causing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are reference types.

`Object.create(null)` returns really empty object without prototype. For example:

```
var emptyObj = Object.create(null)
emptyObj.hasOwnProperty // Return undefined.
emptyObj.prototype // Return undefined.
```

So:

```
createObject.prototype.toObject = function() {
  var objData = this.result.split('&');
  this.result = Object.create(null); //{}
  var res = Object.create(null);
  objData.forEach(function(value, index) {
    var test = value.split('=')
    return res[test[0]] = test[1];
  });

  // Here you say - this.result = res
  // But it's reference type, so the address of this variable will be
  // Setted to `this`
  this.result = res;

  // here you change the reference value of res.
  // so this.result will be = Object.create(null) after next line exec.
  res = Object.create(null);

  return this.result;

}
```

I think this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating this.result off of the `res` object, created with `Object.create(null)` - that uses `null` as its prototype, so it does not have any initial properties.  You end up assigning some properties in the statement

```
return res[test[0]] = test[1];
```

but hasOwnProperty is not among them.  You can create empty objects with `Object.create(Object)` instead.

And you want to use the version that does not have `key` in quotes:

```
  //     if(objIn.hasOwnProperty(key)){
```